# Magento - Create different store view (languages) on the same domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, subdomain, magento-1.9

I create more store views in my Magento 1.9 store, how I can add a subdomain per each store view.

For example I create a new store with the name eu where I setup the language to be english and I need to add a subdomain for this store view: **eu.example.com** but my url is something like this: **http://example.com/?___store=de&___from_store=eu**.

I made the steps like in this image, what I need to do to have this subdomain: **eu.example.com** to the **eu** store view?

[image]

Also I try to add something like this in .htaccess without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eu.example.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:eu]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this in your vhost file :

```
SetEnvIf Host ".*eu.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE=eu MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Comment: in vhost? this is not for .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

No Need to change htaccess just need to manage the subdomain

Follow this steps:

1. change the secure/unsecure url for associated store
2. Configure Subdomain/If you are using Local Machine then assign virtual host with same directory
3. Just run the site it's working well

[image]